# Does a battery's charging current depend on its capacity?

Tags: batteries, current, battery-charging, lithium-ion, capacitance

I'm learning about charging 3.7 V Li-ion batteries.

I'm not sure what the charging current should be for a single battery, let alone for batteries connected in parallel.

My question is related to batteries in general and not to a specific battery.

Comment: You may want to read and process a web page located [at this Digikey page](https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/blogs/2021/charging-lithium-ion-and-lipo-batteries-the-right-way). Then refine your question, perhaps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does a battery's charging current depend on its capacity?

The charging current depends directly on the capacity of the battery, all other things being equal.

When you read literature about batteries, you will come across *C-rate*.  For example: "The battery was charged at 0.5C ."  It's not temperature in Celsius, and it's not capacitance in Farads.  C-rate is current in Amperes that's numerically equal to the capacity of the battery in Ampere-hours.  Charging a 3Ah battery at 0.5C means that the charging current is 1.5A .  Max charging current is usually expressed as C-rate.

The max charging rate and the max discharging rate varies, depending on construction of the battery.  The values should be in the battery's datasheet ([example](https://www.jauch.com/downloadfile/5c3d9cd710f29e9c09d67ef33e58d94ac/3350mah_-_li18650jp_1s1p_2_wires_70mm.pdf)).

There's a tradeoff between the charging time and the number of charge cycles that the battery will last.  If the battery is charged more slowly, it will live for a longer number of charge cycles.

> I'm not sure what the charging current should be for a single battery, let alone for batteries connected in parallel.

[This article](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-409-charging-lithium-ion) should give you the general picture.

Charge current for cells in parallel scales linearly with the number of cells.
But series connection of cells is more complicated, because it requires cell balancing.

Comment: Ok thanks, but lets take for example the 3Ah 0.5C battery, what is the minimum current that I can charge this battery(average)? Would the battery last for a longer number of charge cycles?

Comment: What is important is not to exceed **max** charging current. If minimum current is not noted (it usually isn't), you can often go as low as it makes sense for your use case (but note that at some point you'll be charging less than battery self-discharge - where "charging" doesn't make sense anymore). In practice, you probably wouldn't go below 0.1C, unless you had a reason to.